# Getting an error when trying to use react-native-billing library for making test purchase

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to do a test buying using react-native-billing library.
I do this way:

```
 buy() {
    const InAppBilling = require("react-native-billing");
    InAppBilling.open()
      .then(() => InAppBilling.purchase('android.test.purchased'))
      .then((details) => {
        console.log("You purchased: ", details)
        return InAppBilling.close()
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

and I get an error like this:
"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'InAppBillingBridge.open')"

In the library there is a code like this:

```
"use strict";

const InAppBillingBridge = require("react-native").NativeModules.InAppBillingBridge;

class InAppBilling {
    static open() {
      return InAppBillingBridge.open();  // error is here
    }
}
```

i.e. InAppBillingBridge is undefined
But I don't understand why.
Did somebody face this problem?

Comment: put your android code here

Comment: const InAppBilling = require("react-native-billing");
    InAppBilling.open()
      .then(() => InAppBilling.purchase('android.test.purchased'))
      .then((details) => {
        console.log("You purchased: ", details)
        return InAppBilling.close()
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

Comment: I am also facing with this issue.